# Creating global array of objects (java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, global

So I'm working on a Space Invaders theme project, and I have most of my classes up and running and have started on the animation. Part of the process is the ship's weapons.

I have a class for the weapons, as below (Focus on the constructor):

```
    /**
 * @(#)Weapon.java
 *
 *
 * @author Tristan Nel - 18179460
 * @version 1.00 2015/3/4
 */


public class Weapon {

    private String type;
    private int damage;
    private int rof; //rate of fire
    private int orientation;
    private int firingStage; //0 - not firing ; 1 - flash & recoil ; 2 - bullet
    private String[] sprites; //Set of sprite image file names

    public Weapon() {
    }

    public Weapon(String type, int damage, int rof, int orientation, int firingStage, String[] sprites)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.rof = rof;
        this.orientation = orientation;
        this.firingStage = firingStage;
        this.sprites = sprites;
    }

    //GET and SET Methods
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setDamage(int damage)
    {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void setROF(int rof)
    {
        this.rof = rof;
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation)
    {
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    public void setFiringStage(int firingStage)
    {
        this.firingStage = firingStage;
    }

    public void setSprites(String[] sprites)
    {
        this.sprites = sprites;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public int getDamage()
    {
        return this.damage;
    }

    public int getROF()
    {
        return this.rof;
    }

    public int getOrientation()
    {
        return this.orientation;
    }

    public int getFiringStage()
    {
        return this.firingStage;
    }

    public String[] getSprites()
    {
        return this.sprites;
    }

}
```

In another class, which handles all elements on the game screen to be animated, I want to have a global array of hardcoded Weapon types that can be accessed as needed without fuss. I have attempted to do so at the top of the contents of the class:

```
    /**
 * @(#)GameScreen.java
 *
 *
 * @author Tristan Nel - 18179460
 * @version 1.00 2015/3/4
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class GameScreen {

    private static final String HIGH_SCORE_FILE = "highScore.txt";

    //Available Weapons
    //UPDATED SINCE ORIGINAL POST
    public static final Weapon[] WEAPONS = new Weapon[4];
    WEAPONS[0] = new Weapon("Machinegun",       10, 20, 0, 0,   {Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM});
    WEAPONS[1] = new Weapon("Plasma MG",        20, 20, 0, 0,   {Graphics.PMG_L_NORM, Graphics.PMG_R_NORM});
    WEAPONS[2] = new Weapon("Photon Cannon",        40, 5, 0, 0,    {Graphics.PC_L_NORM, Graphics.PC_R_NORM});
    WEAPONS[3] = new Weapon("Alien Destabilizer",   60, 10, 0, 0,   {Graphics.AD_L_NORM, Graphics.AD_R_NORM});

    private Ship defender;
    private Weapon equipped;
    //private Invader[] aliens;
    //private Bullet[] bullets;
    private int score;
    private int highscore;
    private int lives;

    public GameScreen() {
    }

    public GameScreen(Ship defender, int score, int lives)
    {
        this.defender = defender;
        this.score = score;
        this.lives = lives;
    }

    public void loadHighscore()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(HIGH_SCORE_FILE));
            this.highscore = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            sc.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
            System.out.println(fnf);
            this.highscore = 0;
        }

    }

    public void saveHighScore(int highscore)
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter(HIGH_SCORE_FILE);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(write);
            pw.print(this.highscore);

            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    //GET and SET methods
    public void setDefender(Ship defender)
    {
        this.defender = defender;
    }

    public void setScore(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void setLives(int lives)
    {
        this.lives = lives;
    }

    public Ship getDefender()
    {
        return this.defender;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public int getLives()
    {
        return this.lives;
    }

}
```

This gives me the following error messages on each line that I try to add another element to the array:

UPDATED
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ye7Ul2JDG2NDFDRTJNM1FCd0U/view?usp=sharing

It is highly frustrating..
I read somewhere that you have to create an object within a method? (Eg. main() )
But I tried that in my driver class and it made no difference...

Will appreciate any help/advice (:

Comment: Sorry the word wrap doesn't make the error report very readable.
Please download the error.txt from my Google Drive to examine it correctly
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ye7Ul2JDG2NERKaE5wcVhNMlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you must use the new keyword

Comment: I haven't looked carefully at the errors but I can tell you that an object declaration requires `new`, ie. `new Weapon(stuff-goes-here)`. I would assume the amount of errors means this is the least of your problems.

Comment: Are you sure that passing `{Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}` to `String[] sprites` is a valid way to do this? I don't know myself, just trying to think with you here. If you put those two in an array already and passed that as argument to the constructor...

Comment: Added in the new keyword @ValentinWaeselynck , it unfortunately didn't help

Comment: See above, @SimplyPanda . Was an accident, fixed it but the errors remain..

Comment: @WonderWorld , My class Graphics contains public static final String variables that can be called, for example MG_L_NORM

Java would imo be a very lazy language if it can't handle calling those variables into a object declaration?

Comment: I just have doubt that `{Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}` will be recognized as an array by the constructor parameters.

Comment: @WonderWorld, your suspicion was correct. I was supposed to write that parameter as follows: new String[] {Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues

- You cannot have arbitrary code in the body of your class, e.g. the `WEAPONS[0] =` calls. However, you can initialize the array directly using new Type[]{} syntax. You could also use a static initializer static {} but this is not recommended.
- Also, you need to use the constructor via new keyword, it's not just a method, i.e. `new Weapon()` not `Weapon()`
- You cannot declare arrays using {}, i.e. `new String[]{{Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}}` not `{Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}`

Working version

```
public static final Weapon[] WEAPONS = new Weapon[] {
    new Weapon("Machinegun",       10, 20, 0, 0,   new String []{Graphics.MG_L_NORM, Graphics.MG_R_NORM}),
    new Weapon("Plasma MG",        20, 20, 0, 0,   new String []{Graphics.PMG_L_NORM, Graphics.PMG_R_NORM}),
    new Weapon("Photon Cannon",        40, 5, 0, 0,    new String []{Graphics.PC_L_NORM, Graphics.PC_R_NORM}),
    new Weapon("Alien Destabilizer",   60, 10, 0, 0,   new String []{Graphics.AD_L_NORM, Graphics.AD_R_NORM})
};
```

Comment: You are a wizard, worked perfectly. I was a bit dense to not realize that I had to use the new keyword for an array of Strings as a parameter. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I put it wrongly before but it looks like you need to call the constructor using the new operator like this.

```
arrayName[0] = new Weapon();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since those classes seem somewhat static, something else to look into is using enums for this. This will help avoid complications when you have to search for a particular Weapon. A better design would be to have a WeaponType enum containing all the static immutable data in relation to a Weapon and have the Weapon class contain all the state data.